# Using functions as statements on Python

Tags: javascript, python, functions

A great feature of Javascript is function statements. You can do this:

```
(function myFunc(){
    doSomething();
    doSomethingElse();
})();
```

Which is a way to declare a function and call it without having to refer to it twice. Can that be mimified on Python?

Comment: You've got it the wrong way around. The function in your snippet is used as expression (which contains statements), and function definition being an expression is precisely what one would need to do the same thing in Python. `def` *is* a statement in Python.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not have this syntax for functions.  It does, however, support the lambda syntax which can be used in this way.  However, a lambda is an expression and not a statement, so it is limited.

```
(lambda x: x*x)(10)
```

would return 100

When this feature is needed, just use the `def` statement to define a function

```
...
def tmp(x,y):
   foo(x);
   foo(y);

tmp(12,24)
...
```